# Filtering against properties of objects in an array with a predicate

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios, properties, predicate

I have an array of objects that I'd like to filter using a predicate, but I've not been able to figure out the syntax (or whether it's impossible).

Let's say the object is **location** and it has properties of **latitude** and **longitude**. I've got an array of these called **allLocations** and I want to produce a new array of locations where the latitude property is greater than 30.

When fetching managed objects you can simply use the property name, but not so with arrays:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude > 30.0"];
```

returns no matches (despite there being plenty of location objects with latitudes > 30.0.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.latitude > 30.0"];
```

is no good either, while

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"[SELF latitude] > 30.0"];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"[location latitude] > 30.0"];
```

throw exceptions.

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method of NSArray. Your first  predicate attempt above will work fine when you pass it to that method.

It's worth noting that NSMutableArray uses a different method to achieve a similar effect, `filterUsingPredicate:`. The MutableArray version alters the receiver, whereas the Array version returns a new Array.

Reference:
[NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a)
[NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/filterUsingPredicate%3a)

Comment: filteredArrayUsingPredicate is certainly what I'm using, but I get an empty array from the first predicate, hence my question. I'll play with it again to ensure I'm not missing something, but the empty array is why I posted the question.

Comment: What is the type of `latitude`? I just ran some predicate tests on an array of objects with a numerical property, and the equivalent of your first predicate worked fine for properties of type `float` as well as `NSNumber`.

Comment: Despite being 100% certain I was running the predicate against an NSArray, I was instead running it against an NSMutableArray. I'm surprised there was no complaint during the build. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dodo asked what "latitude > 30.0" refers to. In my case the objects in the array have a property named "latitude". My predicate filtered the list to include only objects where the value of the *latitude* property was greater than 30.0.